# Default row for SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

DB - Oracle

```
create table customer_exercise(
customer_id number,
exercise_id number,
cnt number,
exercise_date date)
```

Data

```
1000    10  3   14-AUG-17
1001    20  6   14-AUG-17
1000    20  2   14-AUG-17
```

Is it possible to get a default row when the record does not exist for the condition in in clause?

```
select customer_id, exercise_id, sum(cnt)
from customer_exercise 
where customer_id in (1000, 1001, 1003)
  and exercise_id in (10, 20)
group by customer_id, exercise_id
order by sum(cnt)
```

result of above query-

```
1000    20  2
1000    10  3
1001    20  6
```

Since customer-ids in the in clause may not have a record for certain exercise-ids, is it possible using SQL to get a result like the one below with sum as 0 for those? For e.g. 1001 does not have a record for exercise-id=10, so sum will be 0.

```
1001    10  0
1003    10  0
1003    20  0
1000    20  2
1000    10  3
1001    20  6
```

Comment: use coalesce(sum(cnt), 0)

Comment: Do you have other tables listing all the customer IDs and exercise IDs?

Comment: Yes, customer_exercise is a many-many mapping table. There is a customer table and exercise table with the customer info and exercise info.

Comment: Your sample data has id's 1000 and 1001, but the expected result also includes id 1002 and 1003. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn your `in` clause conditions into collections (such as a [built-in collection type, handy for this sort of thing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADDCI/ext_types_ref.htm)), expand them into relational data in CTEs, and then cross-join them; and left-join to the real table to see what matches:

```
with customer_cte (customer_id) as (
  select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1000, 1001, 1003))
),
exercise_cte (exercise_id) as (
  select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(10, 20))
)
select c.customer_id, e.exercise_id, coalesce(sum(ce.cnt), 0) as total_cnt
from customer_cte c
cross join exercise_cte e
left join customer_exercise ce
on ce.customer_id = c.customer_id
and ce.exercise_id = e.exercise_id
group by c.customer_id, e.exercise_id
order by coalesce(sum(cnt), 0), customer_id, exercise_id
/

CUSTOMER_ID EXERCISE_ID  TOTAL_CNT
----------- ----------- ----------
       1001          10          0
       1003          10          0
       1003          20          0
       1000          20          2
       1000          10          3
       1001          20          6

6 rows selected.
```

If you already do have separate `customer` and `exercise` tables, and they contain at least all the IDs you're looking for, then you can use those directly instead, and filter against them instead of your mapping table:

```
select c.customer_id, e.exercise_id, coalesce(sum(ce.cnt), 0) as total_cnt
from customer c
cross join exercise e
left join customer_exercise ce
on ce.customer_id = c.customer_id
and ce.exercise_id = e.exercise_id
where c.customer_id in (1000, 1001, 1003)
and e.exercise_id in (10, 20)
group by c.customer_id, e.exercise_id
order by coalesce(sum(cnt), 0), customer_id, exercise_id
```

You won't get default rows for any IDs that don't exist in the `customer` and `exercise` tables this way, but that may not be an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 1000 AS customer_id FROM DUAL UNION 
        SELECT 1001 FROM DUAL UNION 
        SELECT 1003 FROM DUAL) s
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 10 AS exercise_id FROM DUAL UNION 
              SELECT 20 FROM DUAL) s2
)
SELECT c.customer_id , c.exercise_id, COALESCE(sum(ce.cnt),0) AS s
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN customer_exercise ce
  ON c.customer_id = ce.customer_id
 AND c.exercise_id = ce.exercise_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.exercise_id
ORDER BY s;
```

**[DB Fiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7cbc59b4e5f54855f29a44679ebadee5)**

---

Of course you have multiple options to generate `CROSS JOIN` inside cte:

- hardcoded values
- temporary table
- subquery